# Trigger event with sender from subscripted event or this?

Tags: c#, events

Imagine I have a class (form / window) that has a button. In my class I subscribe the button to a method and I throw my own event in it:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, MyEventArgs e);
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
protected virtual void OnMyEvent(MyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (this.MyEvent != null) this.MyEvent(this, e); 
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnMyEvent(???, ???);
}
```

What is the correct way to trigger my event. Should I use `this` with my own `EventArgs`?

```
this.OnMyEvent(this, new EventArgs());
```

Or should I send my sender and event arguments down to the subscription of my own event?

```
this.OnMyEvent(sender, e);
```

What is the correct way. Should we stick to one method only? How is Microsoft doing it? Any code guidelines?

Thank you.

Comment: depends on what your eventhandler needs imo. Does it need the eventargs from the button? Of does it need new eventargs? Or perhaps it doesn ot need eventargs at all and you can remove them from the signature?

Comment: refer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer So MS uses `this` as sender.

Answer (score 1):

Think about who will be subscribing to your event. Will they need to know if it came from a button? Or will they only need to know that it was fired?

Personally I would prefer the listener to only know the event was triggered and the sender is my class which gives me the freedom to change who can fire the event in the first place e.g. button click, timer etc.

Comment: Would it really be that good to let it depend on the case of the subscriber? I would prefer a rule for this and stick to it. Since `sender` is always `object` in the first place, different cases would cause confusion, it would not?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean a specific subscriber but any subscriber. I would be consistent and always set the sender to the same object, in this case it would be the class where you have defined the MyEventHandler delegate.

Comment: This is what I believe in, too. My event is defined in `this` and it's *me* who is raising the event, even when a button event has triggered *me* to do so. I've exchanged opinions with other programmers and many different opinions turned out.